# Where is default protocol mapping stored in WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I want to change `http` scheme binding from `basicHttpBinding` to `wsHttpBinding`. I know i can override it into `app.config`. But that will require changing the setting in all WCF host applications that are impacted.

I also could not found the protocol mapping section in machine.config.

Default protol mapping is as follows.

```
<protolMapping>
    <add scheme ="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
    <add scheme ="tcp"  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
..
</protocolMapping>
```

After change it should look like.

```
<protolMapping>
    <add scheme ="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
    <add scheme ="tcp"  binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" />
..
</protocolMapping>
```

Comment: Don't post screencaps of code. Instead, post the code. If you do not know how to format code properly, please click the big fat orange question mark on the right side of the formatting toolbar.

Comment: Edited and removed screencaps.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the defaults are implemented in code, not in .config file, if you look at the [ProtocolMappingSection Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.protocolmappingsection.aspx), method [InitializeDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.initializedefault.aspx) with a tool such as Reflector or equivalent, you will see this:

```
protected override void InitializeDefault()
{
    this.ProtocolMappingCollection.Add(new ProtocolMappingElement("http", "basicHttpBinding", ""));
    this.ProtocolMappingCollection.Add(new ProtocolMappingElement("net.tcp", "netTcpBinding", ""));
    this.ProtocolMappingCollection.Add(new ProtocolMappingElement("net.pipe", "netNamedPipeBinding", ""));
    this.ProtocolMappingCollection.Add(new ProtocolMappingElement("net.msmq", "netMsmqBinding", ""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Defaults are set in the machine.config and can be overwritten in the web.config / app.config if they do not exist in the machine.config this maybe because the server was not set up with WCF Preinstalled. Normally this would be installed and configured with IIS but if IIS is not installed or not being used to host WCF then WCF Feature would not be.

[MSDN Link on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816881(v=vs.110).aspx)